# ¿Por qué no me crea el commit cuando se modifica el archivo?

Tags: git, git-commit

Creé un archivo de .php que se llama **fichero_3.php**. En él puse el siguiente código:

```
<?php
echo "hola";
```

Una vez lo tengo, hice un commit en Git con el siguiente comando:

```
git commit -m "Este es el archivo 3"
```

Una vez lo tengo hecho el commit empecé a modificar el archivo **fichero_3.php** en el siguiente código:

```
<?php
echo "hola v2";
```

Voy a crear otro commit con el siguiente comando:

```
git commit -m "Archivo 3 modificado"
```

Y resulta que no hace nada. No crea el commit.

Comprobé a ver cómo está el estado del repositorio con el comando `git status`, y dice que no hay nada que haga commit y que el árbol está limpio.

O sea, me permite hacer commit cuando se crea un archivo dentro del repositorio, pero no me crea el commit cuando se modifica el archivo. ¿Por qué no me deja?

Comment: Si estas usando Visual Studio Code como editor de codigo, este viene integrado con git y puedes manipular los archivos que quieres agregar a cada commit con el entorno grafico, para que si dado el caso que tengas x cantidad de archivos manipulados y quieras hacer commits especificos con cada uno, no tengas que annadirlos de forma escrita en la terminal o no tengas que hacer un unico commit con tooooooooooooodas las modificaciones. Aparte, se que suena tonto pero... te aseguraste de guardar los archivos que deseas annadir al commit? creo que un **ctrl+S** en cada archivo es importante.

Comment: El commit no se hace de todos los archivos que has modificado, sino de los archivos que has preparado (stage) para el commit con el comando `add`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es eso porque primero tienes que agregar los archivos modificados. Si quieres incorporar todos los cambios realizados debes usar `git add .` Este comando permite añadir los archivos que tienen cambios al staging area a la espera de confirmación.

Posteriormente creas tu commit con `git commit -m "commit de prueba"` y lo envías al repositorio remoto con `git push origin main`

[Acá](https://www.atlassian.com/es/git/tutorials/saving-changes#:%7E:text=El%20comando%20git%20add%20a%C3%B1ade,concreto%20en%20la%20pr%C3%B3xima%20confirmaci%C3%B3n.) tienes más información.